# How to check if iPhone app is compatible for IPv6 only network from India

Tags: ios, iphone, ipv6, ios10.2

My app is live on the apple app store. When I resubmit my app's new version on the app store the rejected it by saying that it structs in an infinite loading process when tested on iOS 10.2 on IPv6 only network. They provided a screen shot of the view where it structs. Which indicates that it is not able to load data from the gmail server. I used this link http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-how-to-test-your-app-for-ipv6-compatibility/ to create IPv6 network from my Mac. Then I connected my iPhone with iOS 10.2 to this network. My app is working fine on this network too. I live in India. Is it possible that my app is making connection to the gmail server using IPv4 network even though I have setup IPv6 network from my Mac.

Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tested your app using jio network. It was one currently supporting IPv6 in India.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Yes I have used the application over the jeo network. it is working fine on jeo net. But the apple app review team said that we have to check on wifi over the ipv6 network only. As is said in the question above, I have followed the steps given in the link above and tested the app, it is working fine. I cannot understand where the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

You can check IPv6 with JIO network in India.

Instruction for IPv6 configurations is available in the below link 
[Supporting IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Networks](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW1)

In the above under the topic **Test for IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Compatibility Regularly** you can find the steps for checking IPv6 compatibility.

Comment: Yes i have used these instructions and my app is working fine.

Comment: Then you need to check with apple support.

Comment: have you ever come to face this problem :)

Comment: I did not change anything in my code. I put a request to Apple review board that I have checked my app by following the instructions in "Test for IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Compatibility Regularly". They reviewed the app and accepted it. I think they just want the users to know more about IPv6.

Answer (score 0):

I did not change anything in my code. I put a request to Apple review board that I have checked my app by following the instructions in "Test for IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Compatibility Regularly". It is running well. They again reviewed my app and passed it. I think Apple wants the developers to know more about IPv6 network.